# Problems Centering iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am embedding a digital catalog I created with FlipHTML5 and I wanted to make it more mobile friendly.  I added the following CSS:

```
.size {
width: 85vw;
height: 75vh;
```

As setting width/height in the iframe tag wasnt translating well to mobile. Now with this, things are displaying correctly on mobile (both phone and ipad) but im left with the iframe being off center on desktop.  Ive tried setting the iframe to align center, tried putting the iframe inside a centered

tag, tried to put the iframe in a centered  but all with the same issue.  Im left with a large margin on the left side unless i drop the width down to around 60vw in the CSS but then it shows up too thin on mobile.  Is there something im missing or a way to set a different size CSS for mobile?

Comment: did you try `margin: auto;`? It helps quite a bit if you include your code as an example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Add display:block ;margin:0px auto. It will come to center automatically

Comment: Just tried adding that to the css and no change.  If it makes any difference, im on a wordpress site and im adding the CSS through the themes "additional CSS" tab when i go to customize the theme.  Im basically learning most of this as I go so any help is appreciated

Comment: Code for the iframe is below: 
<iframe class="size" src="http://online.fliphtml5.com/hvqs/hqxx/#p=1"></iframe>

then I only have that size css for it.  page it is on is here: http://teranicouture.com/digitalcatalogs/2017ssprom/ at least the one im testing on

Answer (score 0):

Changed my CSS to use the media queries:

```
@media (min-width : 1024px) {
.size {
    width: 65vw;
    height: 75vh;
}
}

@media (max-width : 1024px) {

    .size {
        width: 85vw;
        height: 75vh;
}
}
```

this seems to have fixed the problem of how it looks on desktop while still showing sized right on mobile.  It appears that the whole wordpress site is not centered - the iframe aligns with our logo on the left and when you rezie the window the whole left margin gets larger than the right making the page off center to the right.  weird